# wrong net cash flow in the webpage or not?

Tags: cash-flow

`net cash flow` was defined as sum of `operating cash flow` and  `investing cash flow` and `financing cash flow` in the webpage: https://stockanalysis.com/stocks/adbe/financials/cash-flow-statement/.

The raw data is as below:
[cash flow data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMOgv.png)

```
year                        2022
net income                  4756
depreciation & amortization 939
share-based compensation    1440
other operating activities  703
operating cash flow         7838
operating cash flow growth  8.41%
capital expenditures        -442
acquisitions                -126
change in investments       -2
investing cash flow         -570
share issuance / repurchase -6272
debt issued / paid          0
other financing activities  -553
financing cash flow         -6825
net cash flow               392
free cash flow              7396
free cash flow growth       7.47%
free cash flow margin       42.01%
free cash flow per share    15.74
```

I calculate with the raw data:

```
net cash flow in 2022 = operating cash flow + investing cash flow + financing cash flow
                      = 7838 +(-570) +(-6825)
                      = 443
```

Why the data on the webpage is `392`,not as same as i calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at a [slightly more detailed cash flow statement](https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/ADBE/financials/cash-flow), there is an additional factor in the cash flow statement to account for exchange rate changes - meaning, if ADBE had a significant cash position in Euros, and their cash flow statement is reported in US Dollars, then the Net Cash Flow (meaning the total change in cash) would be different than the sum of what was spent and received if the USD value of that cash in EUR changed.

The aggregator you use does not seem to account for that line in the cash flow statement. It depends on what you're using that data for as to whether you want the total net cash flow or just the change in cash.

Answer (score 0):

The Exchange Rate Effect in 2022 is (51M) as disclosured in marketwatch:
[exchage rate effect](https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/ADBE/financials/cash-flow)

```
net cash flow in 2022 = operating cash flow + investing cash flow + financing cash flow + exchange rate effect 
                  = 7838 +(-570) +(-6825) + (-51)
                  = 443 -51
                  = 392
```